# Is it possible to use Ubuntu's text rendering engine in my OpenGL program?

Tags: opengl, ubuntu

Is there a separate library or component that renders text in Ubuntu? How to write a OpenGL program that renders text exactly the same as the system?

[image]

Comment: No, I mean the rendering techniques. For example, the subpixel rendering. You can see that in programs like Chromium, they can render text just like the menu text in Ubuntu. Are they using some libraries? I knew `freetype` can be used to render text, but program rendered using `freetype` will not be controlled by system settings, such as `.fonts.conf` file.

Comment: Well, all programs like Chromium use the GTK library, which probably uses Pango for the text rendering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you get down to the bottom of any modern font rendering technology on Linux you'll usually find FreeType. You might also hear the word "Pango" come up. GTK on Ubuntu uses Pango as a text layout engine, but as I understand it Pango is just a multi-language text layout engine, and still uses FreeType for rasterization, which is probably all you're looking for. FreeType will rasterize your text strings, and then you can load them as textures.

Check out the API docs for FreeType:
http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html

And the tutorial pages:
http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/documentation.html

Comment: You do need Pango to correctly render a paragraph of Unicode text. Using FreeType alone without Pango-equivalent logic will give you a "toy" text renderer, essentially it will only be correct in Latin scripts. There are Pango alternatives, for example Qt has something built in.

Answer (score 1):

you might have a look at COGL and Clutter source code for an example with GL. The text library is Pango, which builds on FreeType.